# Why Redux Saga yield call return a function, not data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, redux-saga

I am trying to practice redux saga,

I have a question which is not return a data from `async await`.

With following codes :

/src/sagas/todos/index.js

```
export function* fetchTodosSaga() {

    console.log('Ready to fetch Todos ...');

    try {

        const _todos = yield call(fetchTodos);
        console.log(_todos); // Not a Result Data, It is a function

        yield put({
            type: "FETCH_TODOS_FULFILLED",
            payload: {
                todos: _todos
            }
        });

    } catch (e) {

        yield put({ 
            type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED", 
            message: e.message 
        });

    }

    return 'Hello';

}
```

/src/actions/sagas/todos.js

```
 export const fetchTodos = (params) => async (dispatch) => {
     try {

         const getTodosResponse = await todosAPI.getTodos(params);
         console.log(getTodosResponse.data); // It is a CORRECT data
         dispatch(fetchTodosAction(getTodosResponse.data));
         return Promise.resolve(getTodosResponse.data);
         
     } catch (error) {
         return Promise.reject(error);
     }
 }
```

/src/services/api/todos/index.js

```
 export default {
     async getTodos() {
         try {
             return await axios.get(`${ baseUrl }/${ routes.todos }`);
         } catch (error) {
             return Promise.reject(error);
         }
     }
 }
```

And the Result of Console from chrome inspector

```
ƒ (_x) {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

How should i fix the issue ?

Comment: so you can callback that function after success in database, so both are in sync

Comment: Thx @AshishKamble, I'm still not understand which part can callback ? Would you mind try to code your comment ?

Comment: I realise this is very late to the party, but just don't use redux or redux saga. Saga is a hot mess, makes code almost unreadable. Everything is better off just using Context if you want to pass down some global state like user auth details. Generator functions do not make for easy reading at the best of times and saga makes this so much worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc [call(fn, ...args)](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#callfn-args):

> `fn: Function` - A Generator function, or normal function which either returns a Promise as result, or any other value.

But you passed a thunk to `call`. The thunk returns a function rather than a promise or a non-function value. That's why `_todos` is a function.

When you use `redux-saga`, you don't need to use `redux-thunk`.  You should pass the API call function `todosAPI.getTodos` to the `call` effect creator.

E.g.

```js
import { runSaga } from 'redux-saga';
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

const todosAPI = {
  async getTodos() {
    return { data: ['a', 'b', 'c'] };
  },
};

export function* fetchTodosSaga() {
  try {
    const _todos = yield call(todosAPI.getTodos);
    console.log(_todos);
    yield put({ type: 'FETCH_TODOS_FULFILLED', payload: { todos: _todos } });
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({ type: 'USER_FETCH_FAILED', message: e.message });
  }

  return 'Hello';
}

(function test() {
  let dispatched = [];
  runSaga({ dispatch: (action) => dispatched.push(action), getState: () => {} }, fetchTodosSaga);
})();
```

Output:

```sh
{ data: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] }
```